# Silverstripe googlesitemaps module

Tags: php, seo, silverstripe

I have installed the google sitemaps module for SilverStripe 3.0 from

https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-googlesitemaps

I am able to see the sitemap generated by the module...I read that this module notifies Google of any modified or new pages

But for the first time do we have to submit the XML to Google for indexing or even this is done by the module?

Comment: ..and if not around how much time is taken for the site and any pages to be indexed?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend submitting the sitemap.xml to Google for indexing. The module does not submit this automatically, although google would detect it the next time it crawls the site.

Here is some more information on the module:

https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-googlesitemaps/blob/master/docs/en/index.md